# How do I get port 80 to actually open on AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty

I am trying to follow [THIS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) tutorial to set up a LAMP on my ec2, with the eventual goal of setting up a WordPress blog on the instance.  I've set the security group as follows: [LINK TO PICTURE OF MY SECURITY GROUP INBOUND RULES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfLf4.png)

I've completed the setup via PuTTY and am SSHing into the instance just fine.  I ran the `chkconfig --list httpd` command, which output `httpd   0:off   1:off   2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off` just like it should, and then I tried entering the public IPV4 address into my browser, it doesn't give me the apache test page, but rather this: [image of port 80 not actually being open, after all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCBUj.png)

I am using the following AMI: amzn-ami-hvm-2018.03.0.20190611-x86_64-ebs

Help!

**EDIT**
var/log/httpd/error.log doesn't exist, so checking it won't help.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Try `curl http://localhost` from the server to make sure something is running. Then looking into the operating system's firewall settings, like `iptables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install WordPress on your EC2 instance?

If you have not, find your User Data in your EC2 instance settings and add the following:

#!/bin/bash
yum -y update
yum install httpd php php-mysql -y
cd /var/www/html
echo "healthy" > healthy.html
wget https://wordpress.org/wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz
cp -r wordpress/* /var/www/html
rm -rf wordpress
rm -rf wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz
chmod -R 755 wp-content
chown -R apache:apache wp-content
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketforwordpresslab-donotdelete/htaccess.txt
mv htaccess.txt .htaccess
chkconfig httpd on
service httpd start

I hope this works out well for you.

Comment: Try to use the latest Linux AMI

Answer (score 1):

Common issue for new AWS users.

Go to the Ec2 page and click on your instance to show all the details. Click on the security tab and see what your security group is. I'm assuming that your photo looks different than mine. You are probably missing the 80 ::/0 at the bottom that is required to fully open the 80 port. [image: Showing open ports]

I'm guessing the issue is that your security group is not configured correctly.

Click on security group tab on the left bottom of the page. Then click on your security group, if you are using default, you need to make one and have all the ports open. If you have one already, click on it and then click on "Inbound rules"

Then click edit rules. Then add a new line for HTTP and then if you see the source tab, click on that and switch it to anywhere and then it will auto fill with the 0.0.0.0/0 and the ::/0 which is the one I think you need. [image: Advanced routing]